# Powerline Theme in OSX terminal have a strange color

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I configure the powerline theme on OSX like `zsh` `vim` and `emacs`

But it has a strange colour in the ">" character

[image: emacs config line]

[image: zsh config line]

How can I make the the ">" character colour match with the powerline bar

Comment: So the problem you are asking about that it has cyan background when in `/bin` directory? Or that the colour of the triangle does not match the line?

Comment: @techraf the second '/bin' directory is my selection. The color of triangle is different from the front bar

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do about it (except trying a different font).

I had the same "issue" but I don't consider this as something bad.
Get use to it but first try a font that will match as much as possible and will reduce the difference between "rectangle" section and "triangle" section.

[Check my OMZ shell script](https://github.com/komarnicki/shell-scripts/blob/master/macOS/setup.sh) where I use bullet-train theme.

> Bullet Train theme for OMZ requires Powerline Compatible Fonts

Take a look especially at:

```
mkdir $TEMP_FONT_DEST
cd $TEMP_FONT_DEST
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git .
./install.sh
rm -rf $TEMP_FONT_DEST
```

[image]

I will upvote your question because you're new here and to wake up your creativity. Good luck with customising your shell.